# Error attempting to forward engineer? SQL Error 1215

Tags: mysql

I know this question has come up many times on this site already, but as can be seen:

1) Any foreign key referenced in a table is either a primary or unique key in the table in which it is originally defined.

2) No two foreign keys have the same name (dname, dname1, etc.)

3) InnoDB was used for all tables.

Any ideas what might be causing error 1215? 
This is what the error says:

```
Executing SQL script in server
ERROR: Error 1215: Cannot add foreign key constraint
SQL Code:
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        -- Table `mydb`.`major`
        -- -----------------------------------------------------
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`major` (
          `dname2` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
          `sid` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
          PRIMARY KEY (`dname2`, `sid`)  COMMENT '',
          INDEX `sid_idx` (`sid` ASC)  COMMENT '',
          CONSTRAINT `dname2`
            FOREIGN KEY (`dname2`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`dept` (`dname`)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
            ON UPDATE CASCADE,
          CONSTRAINT `sid`
            FOREIGN KEY (`sid`)
            REFERENCES `mydb`.`student` (`sid`)
            ON DELETE CASCADE
            ON UPDATE CASCADE)
        ENGINE = InnoDB

SQL script execution finished: statements: 9 succeeded, 1 failed

Fetching back view definitions in final form.
Nothing to fetch
```

---

This is where my code begins:

```
-- MySQL Workbench Forward Engineering

SET @OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS=@@UNIQUE_CHECKS, UNIQUE_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@@FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS, FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=0;
SET @OLD_SQL_MODE=@@SQL_MODE, SQL_MODE='TRADITIONAL,ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Schema mydb
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS `mydb` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci ;
USE `mydb` ;

-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`student`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`student` (
  `sid` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `sname` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `sex` VARCHAR(7) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `age` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `year` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `gpa` DOUBLE NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`sid`)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`dept`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`dept` (
  `dname` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `numphds` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`dname`)  COMMENT '')
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`prof`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`prof` (
  `pname` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `dname` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`pname`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `dname_idx` (`dname` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `dname`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dname`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`dept` (`dname`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`course`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`course` (
  `cno` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `cname` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `dname1` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`cno`, `dname1`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `dname_idx` (`dname1` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `dname1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dname1`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`dept` (`dname`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`major`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`major` (
  `dname2` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `sid` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`dname2`, `sid`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `sid_idx` (`sid` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `dname2`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dname2`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`dept` (`dname`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `sid`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sid`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`student` (`sid`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`section`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`section` (
  `dname3` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `cno` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `sectno` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `pname` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`dname3`, `cno`, `sectno`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `cno_idx` (`pname` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `dname3`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cno`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`dept` (`dname`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `cno`
    FOREIGN KEY (`pname`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`course` (`cno`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `pname`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`prof` ()
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


-- -----------------------------------------------------
-- Table `mydb`.`enroll`
-- -----------------------------------------------------
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `mydb`.`enroll` (
  `sid1` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `grade` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `dname4` VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `cno1` VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  `sectno` INT NOT NULL COMMENT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`sid1`, `dname4`, `cno1`, `sectno`)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `dname_idx` (`dname4` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `cno_idx` (`cno1` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  INDEX `sectno_idx` (`sectno` ASC)  COMMENT '',
  CONSTRAINT `sid1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sid1`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`student` (`sid`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `dname4`
    FOREIGN KEY (`dname4`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`dept` (`dname`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `cno1`
    FOREIGN KEY (`cno1`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`course` (`cno`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE,
  CONSTRAINT `sectno`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sectno`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`section` (`sectno`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE)
ENGINE = InnoDB;


SET SQL_MODE=@OLD_SQL_MODE;
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS=@OLD_FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS;
SET UNIQUE_CHECKS=@OLD_UNIQUE_CHECKS;
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple of issues with these definitions:

No names are provided for this foreign key definition.

```
CONSTRAINT `pname`
    FOREIGN KEY ()
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`prof` ()
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

Enroll table is attempting to create a foreign key on a non leading column in a primary key index.

```
CONSTRAINT `sectno`
    FOREIGN KEY (`sectno`)
    REFERENCES `mydb`.`section` (`sectno`)
    ON DELETE CASCADE
    ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

The index defined on section is

```
PRIMARY KEY (`dname3`, `cno`, `sectno`)  COMMENT '',
```

With this index structure, a foreign key cannot be enforced. Moving `sectno` to the 1st key in the index will support a foreign key.